# TFS source binding disconnects when close the solution and re open it

Tags: asp.net, .net, tfs

When I close the solution and reopen the solution it will disconnect the source binding and give message TFS is offline how i solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post more details as to what the error message is?

Comment: when i open solution it open without bindings.
then i click on the change source control it will display bellow message.
The current solution is associated with source cotrol but is offline.
Would you like to completely disassociate the solution from source control?

But TFS is online,
To rebind i need to click on yes message and rebind it.
How I solve this problem?